# how to display processes of computers connected to a remote server

Tags: c#

I am trying to do a project for my college lab where we need to display all the processes running of the client systems on the server system. is there and c# code that enables us to do so

Thanking you

Christopher john

Comment: Is this for ASP.NET website or WinForms application?

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8b2hzk8.aspx